# Change the text color of button

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Well i able to change the color of `Button` create using `Createwindow` control using the Custom draw.But button color is still black i want to change this color.Is there any property in `CustomDraw` to change the Text color.
Here is my code for background color change

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam) -> code)
    {
        case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
            if (((LPNMHDR)lParam) -> idFrom == 10002)
            {
                LPNMCUSTOMDRAW lpnmCD = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
                switch (lpnmCD -> dwDrawStage)
                {
                    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
                        SetDCBrushColor(lpnmCD -> hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
                        SetDCPenColor(lpnmCD -> hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
                        SelectObject(lpnmCD -> hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
                        SelectObject(lpnmCD -> hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
                        RoundRect(lpnmCD -> hdc, lpnmCD -> rc.left + 3, lpnmCD -> rc.top + 3,
                        lpnmCD -> rc.right - 3, lpnmCD -> rc.bottom - 3, 5, 5);
                        return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to draw the text yourself.
Add that code after `RoundRect`

```
// Unicode, adapt for ansi
// -----------------------
wchar_t szBtnText[ 32 ] = { 0 };
GetWindowText( ((LPNMHDR)lParam) -> hwndFrom, szBtnText, sizeof(szBtnText) / sizeof(wchar_t) ); 
SetTextColor(lpnmCD -> hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
SetBkMode(lpnmCD -> hdc, TRANSPARENT);
DrawText(lpnmCD -> hdc, szBtnText, wcslen(pszBtnText), &lpnmCD -> rc,
         DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);
return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
```

Comment: Getting error: DrawTextW : cannot convert parameter 2 from char * to LPCWSTR

Comment: which header file is used for _tcslen?

Comment: a common way of dealing with UNICODE/Ansi is to use the <tchar.h> technique. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx I have updated the answer for "unicode only"

Comment: How do you update the pszBtnText variable with the button text?

Comment: Button value is updated dynamically so i think that's the problem